# I have tried various combinations but only the jquery code for smooth scrolling seems to work.

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble using two jQuery codes in the same HTML file.

Out of two codes,only one seems to work

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jq1 = jQuery.noConflict();
```

//This jQuery code is being used to disaapear the drop down menu after the option is being clicked

```
$jq1(function () {
         $jq1('html')
          .on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
          .on('click.dropdown.data-api touchstart.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
         $jq1('body')
        .on('click.dropdown', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() }) 
    </script>




<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" >
```

/*This jquery code is being used for smooth scrolling

I have tried various combinations but only the jquery code for smooth scrolling seems to work.

Only if I somehow disable this code, the other code for drop down works*/

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
$jq(function() {
  $jq('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $jq(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $jq('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $jq('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Kindly help in resolving the issue

Comment: what's the problem you are having? "only the jquery code for smooth scrolling seems to work." so thew code does work?? whats the issue?

Comment: I have two jQuery codes..one for hiding dropdown and other for smooth scrolling in the same HTML file. The two codes are contradicting and only the smooth scrolling takes effect in the web page, not the drop down hiding. If I disbable th smooth scrolling code, then the drop down hiding works. So in any case, only one effect reflects in my web page..but I wish both of them

Comment: you are running two competing pluggins on the same html element/target. they are bound to cause issues